# Is there platform independent, non-blocking way to tell if file descriptor is an on-disk file (regular/directory)

Tags: linux, macos, unix, posix, file-descriptor

I am looking for type of a file descriptor without the possibility of blocking in the kernel. I am aware I can use `fstat(2)` but `fstat` will also get me all sorts of metadata information (access time etc) which may block for an arbitrary amount of time (especially on networked file systems).

EDIT: I am looking for a syscall to do this, spawning a separate process is not acceptable because spawning a process and reading its results is certainly not instant.

The only bit of information I need to know is really if the file descriptor is an on-disk "file" (`S_IFREG`, `S_IFLNK`, `S_IFDIR`) or not. Alternatively, if I could tell if it's a socket (`S_IFSOCK`), fifo (`S_IFIFO`), or character device (`S_IFCHR`) that'd be fine too.

I'm pretty sure any kernel will have this information readily available and I'm interested if that can be surfaced to user-space without blocking.

A portable solution (macOS & Linux at least) would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: reading the filesystem may always block even for the lightest piece of data, thus I don't think you can do that without dedicating a thread for it (especially if you need portability)...

Comment: @OznOg Agreed. And I don't want to read the file system at all which is why I don't want to use `fstat`. But figuring out just the _type_ of an _open_ fd should surely be possible without a disk/fs access.

Comment: Do you mean by "non-blocking" an instantaneous command?

Comment: Non-blocking as the `O_NONBLOCK` flag to the open call which means that an operation returns immediately, whatever happens. I need an immediately returning function that tells me the file type.

Comment: @JohannesWeiss, I asked you this because in your question it seemed like you wanted _to retrieve the result_ immediately. That's not the purpose of a non blocking way as you meant by "whatever happens" in your comment. If you're ready to this "whatever", why spawning a process isn't acceptable? You'll have to loop anyway until you get the result.

Answer (score -1):

On Linux you can look into [`proc` pseudo-filesystem](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), `/proc/<pid>/fd`, e.g.:

```
[max@supernova:/proc/7275/fd] $ ls -l /proc/7275/fd/
total 0
lr-x------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 1 -> 'pipe:[69689]'
lrwx------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 10 -> 'socket:[69698]'
l-wx------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 100 -> '/home/max/.config/google-chrome/Default/Service Worker/Database/MANIFEST-000001'
lr-x------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 101 -> '/home/max/.config/google-chrome/Default/Sync Data/LevelDB/001633.ldb'
l-wx------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 102 -> '/home/max/.config/google-chrome/Default/Service Worker/Database/000024.log'
lr-x------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 103 -> '/home/max/.config/google-chrome/Default/Service Worker/Database/000022.ldb'
lr-x------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 104 -> /opt/google/chrome/nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe
lr-x------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 105 -> '/home/max/.config/google-chrome/Default/Service Worker/Database/000005.ldb'
lr-x------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 106 -> '/home/max/.config/google-chrome/Default/Service Worker/Database/000025.ldb'
lr-x------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 107 -> '/home/max/.config/google-chrome/Default/Service Worker/Database/000019.ldb'
lrwx------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 108 -> 'socket:[89401]'
lrwx------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 109 -> 'socket:[68628]'
lrwx------ 1 max max 64 Oct 12 16:28 11 -> 'anon_inode:[eventfd]'
```

Comment: `/proc` is not cross-platform. MacOS doesn't have it, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the 'lsof' command in non-blocking mode with the arguments '-b'. This argument will cause lsof to avoid kernel functions that might block. For example:

```
sudo lsof -b | less
COMMAND     PID   TID            USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE    SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
systemd       1                  root  cwd       DIR                8,1        4096          2 /
systemd       1                  root  rtd       DIR                8,1        4096          2 /
systemd       1                  root  txt       REG                8,1     1595792      19245 /lib/systemd/systemd
```

The 'TYPE'will give you the type of file it is. You can pipe this with grep to get information about your file descriptor,

```
sudo lsof -b | grep <your file descriptor>
```

Or there are lots of arguments which will allow you to customize the lsof operations.

And for platform independence, these are the platforms on which lsof is supported:-

```
 Apple Darwin 9 and Mac OS X 10.[567]
 FreeBSD 8.[234], 9.0, 10.0 and 11.0 for AMD64-based systems
 Linux 2.1.72 and above for x86-based systems
 Solaris 9, 10 and 11
```

Comment: Running lsof is not non-blocking. It needs to at least read the lsof binary before executing it. I need a system call from within my process.